# hiding php script name in action attribute in html on a cpanel Hosted site

Tags: php, html, cpanel

How can i hide the name of the php script called in action URL in html form on click of submit button . Website is hosted on a cPanel server .

[Image attached for convenience](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Ooi.png)

Comment: Won't really matter if you hide it, anyone looking at their network tab in dev tools will see where the form goes.

Comment: Isn't it good to hide it to prevent some one to access the database through this script?

Comment: If knowing the name of the script allow someone modify your database you have a very big problem. The script should be written in a way that don't allow other queries apart from the ones needed for your application. If you are really worried about security it would be better learn first about [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: right i get it thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write some javascript code to handle the form submit event and specify the target (action) url there, which would remove it from the action attribute directly. But it would still be exposed clientside for anybody looking. Bottom line is the browser needs to have a target url to know where to submit form info to, and there's no way to hide that from a user.

Having said that.. you can always do something server-side like have a single public facing router script based on any number of things, such as an id or certain value to let the server-side script know what to route to, so that the user never directly knows the path of your processing script.

Overall, I would suggest you look into implementing your site using a MVC framework (e.g. Laravel). It does many cool things, including (effectively) solving for your current issue.